# External URL on Cordova/PhoneGap Windows 8 Store Application

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have a Cordova application that I currently use on Android and iOS. This cross platform app uses an external URL as its start page. This works great in Android, iOS and even WP8 but if I add the Windows 8 platform to my Cordova project, the application will not build.

I have found Windows 8 Store Apps running HTML5/Javascript must use local content only. I have been trying to find a way to make my app build but I am not getting very far. I would have thought I would have found similar complaints online but I strangely have found none.

I have thought about trying to use an iFrame within a local HTML page and point it to my external content but runs into formatting issues and lack of plugin support.

I wish Cordova/PhoneGap would not use a HTML5/Javascript project for Windows 8 but a XAML/C# project that embeds a WebView. That is, after all, how all the other main platforms work- even WP8. If there was a way to convert the WP8 project to a Windows 8 app then I could possibly substitute it for the limiting Windows 8 HTML5/Javascript project.

Am I missing something? How do I use a Cordova app for Windows 8 using external content? I surely cannot be the only developer wanting to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use local files that call remote files  using Ajax? That would be your best bet while using html and Javascript on Windows platform.

Comment: It is a very involved Dojo application that would be very difficult to load via ajax calls. Unless you can think of a way to bootstrap the application using some local files and then have it freestanding.

Comment: How big is the application you are talking about? I have done some apps for windows platform using the method I have stated and they aren't enterprise level but they are pretty big. I did the markup, dom calls, and some logic on the client side while any information needed (ie database calls, flat files) was done using ajax and a server side language. It has worked quite well for me.

Comment: Yea the idea was being able to perform in-app updates by using newer version of server side files.